# how to use Reality Gem to query wikidata to find properties such as part_of & Instance_of

Tags: ruby, wikidata

I'm using [Reality Gem](https://github.com/molybdenum-99/reality) to Query Wikidata, using this code below. But it gives nil output. i've checked using result.methods command but i dont't see any method to view "part_of" or "instance_of" property values

```
require 'reality'    
result = Reality::Entity("Enterprise JavaBeans")
result.part_of
=> nil
```

However on wikidata page these properties are available:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q742961

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I am actually trying to do this
result.part_of , but i can't find any way of doing it

Comment: I got it using a very ugly hacky... `w = Wikidata::Entity.one_by_id('Q742961'); e = Reality::Entity::WikidataPredicates.parse(w); e[:part_of]`

Comment: did you type this "Wikidata::Entity" by mistake or you actually used another gem "wikidata" ?

Comment: Ohh.. I'm sorry. Please use the following: `w = Reality::Wikidata::Entity.one_by_id('Q742961')`

Comment: i can confirm that this works. If you like to post an answer, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this error is happening.
I guess it's because the document structures on Wikidata and Wikipedia aren't the same.

But you can get around with the following hacky:

```
require 'reality'

w = Reality::Wikidata::Entity.one_by_id('Q742961')
e = Reality::Entity::WikidataPredicates.parse(w)
e[:part_of]
```